# How do I delete the meta-inf folder in minecraft.jar?

Tags: linux, jar

When I open the minecraft.jar file with p7zip on Linux, I can't delete the META-INF folder.

This is the error:

```
Error: /home/davide/.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar is not supported archive

System error: Operation not permitted
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`p7zip` couldn't open it for me even after renaming it to zip (said "unknown suffix").

My system's default archive manager is `file-roller`, it opened the .jar witout any problems an I could delete the folder.

`unzip` could also handle it, but you need to recompress manually after.